# Twitter Web Intent analogue for Google+

Tags: google-plus

Is there a Twitter Web Intent analogue for Google+?

I want users of my site to have the opportunity to "+" and "share" Google+ posts with **specific ids** in pop-up windows (like in Twitter Web Intent).

Answer (score 0):

The features Google+ provides are all listed on their [documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/web/).

The particular one that might be of interest to you is the [Share button](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/) and corresponding URL.

```
<a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url={URL}" onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href,
  '', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=600');return false;"><img
  src="https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/gplus-64.png" alt="Share on Google+"/></a>
```